# Building a Single Board Computer is in digital electronics design field or analog electronics design field?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, design

Those who build computers like Raspberry are digital electronics designer or analog electronics designer? 
If there are both of them in their team, which parts of the board building is done by digital designer and which parts are done by analog designer?

Is it possible someone with one of the skills(digital or analog) does everything by himself? (I mean how is the percentage of the needed knowledge? if 95% is digital and 5% analog, we can say he can learn that 5% to do everything himself(without knowing much about analog))

Also is there any other skills in their team?

Comment: It's obviously both – digital part for the actual computation part, analog design for the power supply and potential analog signals (video, audio, RF links). Your question is totally impossible to answer, as it is paradox. Since you need both skills, no, someone with only one of these skills *cannot* do that. However, if they attempt to do that, based on how clever they are, they'll go out possessing a bit of both skills. Maybe you want to ask a clearer, well-defined, technical question!

Comment: Also, define "can do": I'm sure one can throw together a bad device that does kind of work, but not very fast, reliable, efficient and so on relatively easily. Designing something that you'd want to be sold a couple thousand times and being used in various applications is something completely different. Just as everyone can be dentist, very few will be a good dentist... Would you want to go to a dentist that knows what he does, or only to one that definitely knows how to pull a tooth, but not much else?

Comment: Also, reading your previous question: Stop trying to be cheaper than someone who has years of experience at producing cheap SBCs. You won't manage to do that, absolutely no way, with your experience and means. Whatever robot you buy will not be sold in even closely the same numbers as these well-tested, well-designed, cost-optimized, tested SBCs. You're beating a dead horse.

Comment: One of my favourite articles: http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/misc/whyjohnny.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is, in a sense, flawed. In asking it, you implicitly assume that there is a nicely defined distinction between Analog and Digital designers.

The reality is much more complicated.

A board like the raspberry can be designed by a single designer. Take for example Robert Feranec, who I believe designed a quite similar board from scratch in one of his "tutorial" series. His youtube channel can be found here:

https://www.youtube.com/user/matarofe

When looking at (Electrical) engineers, they are often jack-of-all-trades, that then specialize further in a specific field - either by education, or by experience. I think most electrical engineers would be able to design a board like the Raspberry Pi, if you give them enough time to study it (how good the board would be is an entirely different matter tho!).

If I were to say what "specific" engineers one might find in the team designing a board like a raspberry pi, that is to be mass produced:

- Powersupply designers
- Digital designers
- Analog designers (although I think they aren't that common for something like a raspberry, there isn't much analog on there, really)
- If the board has wifi, you might find RF engineers
- Often, on larger projects, you have people that specialize on the PCB design itself and are experts on this.
- Large production volume parts might have a person that really knows supply chain management, production processes, etc. This could be a separate engineer (or group of).
- Often on digital boards: Firmware engineers and higher level software engineers, who will port software and/or write the drivers, bootloaders, ...

All of this depends on how far you go, how big your team is, how complex the product is, etc.

TLDR; it's a very complex situation, and you can't really just say there are "analog" and "digital" designers.

Comment: The original Pi was done by about three people with strong digital design backgrounds from Alphamosaic/Broadcom. Wifi wasn't included until they could afford to buy in the necessary RF expertise.

Comment: I was merely giving the Pi as an example. I did not intend to perfectly represent the original design team.

Comment: Sure, that comment was really just for information - this sort of thing *can* be done with a small team if they're good and realistic about scope.

Answer (score 2):

Watched a guy run a place-and-route tool, 25 years ago for an IO_Expander PCB.
I recall wondering at the lack of planes. His VDD and GND were 1/8" wide at most. The MCU/memory was his design. The IO_Expander was his design. And he was key guy at the company (tiny company) because he'd immersed in BIOS and communications protocols, in assembly and C. As he said "While you guys were in college, I was programming on the original PC".

Turns out his IO_Expander board.............caused intermittent resets of the MCU board.

I moved on, to video & RF work (and some assembly code for remote-controls), and moved on to silicon design. My boss asks, one day "You used to work at XXXXX Company. They have intermittents in their controllers, out on the floor. Can you help them?" OK. Each IC had VDD bypass cap (7400 ICs), so the local power held up, but the intermixing of 50 SSI return-currents with 10nS edges was the problem. No scope needed. Just know the Trise, Tfall, the logic input currents for 7400 family.

The original guy had been killed, in a plane crash. OK. Honoring his hard work, I simply said "Those PCBs have no planes. The Grounds cannot be at all quiet. Use planes." and I showed how $$Vupset= Linductance * dI/dT$$
would, with 100nH and 100mA/10nS, produce a volt of GND upset and force logic "0" up into the forbidden region for TTL.

Write the math ......  100nH * 0.1amp/10nS   ...... and notice the 'nano' cancel, so we have 100*0.1/10=1.
Easy math. Pick some easy numbers, and do the math in your head. You get to pick the numbers, so pick easy numbers. If the math predicts a problem ---- you should know the noise margin of your digital ICs by heart ---- then fix the problem.

The problem was PHYSICS, not digital nor analog. The person unwilling to learn physics, out of curiosity if for no other reason, should not be called "engineer".

As a kid, I was able to ignore V = L*dI/dT. As an adult, implementing systems with 120 and 150dB performance, risk control, using the physics, is part of getting successes. Be able to predict volt upsets (to logic) and nanovolt upsets (to power-meters pulling 10ppm measurements from a current-shunt).

EDIT.....details of the 100mA/10nS number: 
TTL gates look like.....10pF input capacitance (silicon junctions + ESD + PCB wiring).
To charge that 10pF from 0v to +3v in 10nS: I = C*dV/dT = 10pF * 3v/10nS = 3mA
The peak current, assuming triangular (realistic) rise and fall of current, is 6mA.
Thus if 17 signals are concurrently switching, the 100mA transient occurs.

Lacking a GND plane, or GND grid, his single daisy-chain GND was destined for trouble because all the transient currents interacted in the shared 1/8" GND routed around the 8" by 16" PCB. Probably had 1/2 meter or 1 meter of GND route, serpentined around the PCB.

There is(was) lots of ringing, and lots of delays through the slow TTL gates, thus only occasionally did the stored energies add up to RESET.

EDIT EDIT Another noise problem arises, in interfacing high-precision ADCs (or DACs) to MCUs. The MCU is never quiet, internally. Assume 0.5 volt ringing at 100MHz. For either logic level. Even when a MCU output driver has been stable for 100nanoSeconds or more, whereupon its own ringing (from its transient) has died out[I use 6dB/10nS to model rate-of-decay for MCUs], the internals of the MCU are still clocking along. Thus the internal GND and VDD are bouncing around, and that "quiet output driver" is not quiet.

What happens, when this logic level connects to an ADC Enable pin? With its ESD/FETgate capacitance, say 10pF? The current is I = C * dV/dT. The dV/dT is d(0.25v*sin(100MHz))/dt = 0.25 * 628,000,000 = 150Million volts/second.

I (injected into the ADC) = 10pF * 150Million = 1e-11 * 1.5e+8 = 1.5milliAmps.
With risetime, triangle waveform assumed, of 5nS.

This current has to exit the ADC and return to the MCU, through a 10nH path.
What is the upset-voltage, inside the ADC?

V = L * dI/dT = 10nH * 1.5mA/5ns (nano cancel) = 10 * 0.0015/5 = 3 milliVolts.

Thus your MCU constantly causes 3  millivolts substrate noise (gnd noise, VDDnoise because *all* possible paths are explored in finding a return path), inside your 16 bit or 18 bit or 24 bit ADC. At the 8 bit or 10 bit or 12 bit level, analog design seems simple. But at the 3mV level (from our computation), cliffs exist.

What if the MCU monitors 16 bits *from* a 16-bit ADC? The ESD diodes of the MCU are coupling the MCU internal bouncing onto those 16 traces back to the ADC.

Comment: Where did you get the 100mA/10nS figure from ? Is that 2mA/10nS per signal ? is that derived from the rise time and load capacitance ?

Comment: You have some good points in this answer but the writing is kind of fragmentary.

Comment: Also needs couple figures?

Answer (score 1):

It's very rare to find someone who is purely a digital or analog engineer. Just about any professional electronics engineer with some experience will know the basics of both and be able to make a reasonable attempt. Of course there is a big difference between knowing the basics and making a reasonable attempt and being an expert.

So a single board computer could be a 1 person job or you could have a whole team:
Digital, analog, power supplies, RF, CAD librarian, PCB layout, mechanical design, DFM expert, test engineer...
Plus a firmware engineer to do the bootstrap and help test/debug.

If it was to be a one man job then a digital electronics engineer is the best guess as to who would have the required skills but that would have to be a very good engineer to do the job well.

Comment: I agree.  I'd describe myself as a predominantly "digital" biased engineer and if I were asked to undertake such a HUGE task on my own then I'd be forced to make use of manufacturer's app notes for things like the SMPS and ethernet PHY circuits and layouts.  These days we are very lucky indeed that certain generous manufacturers (LT, Analog Devices etc etc...) basically give you a complete app note with runnable simulations and even configuration spreadsheets to do all the complex physics calcs that I'm so afraid of.  So all I have to do is carefully implement the recommended boilerplate!

Comment: "So all I have to do is carefully implement the recommended boilerplate! ". You wish! App notes are in my experience more then somewhat variable in quality, and should generally be taken as hints rather then properly tested designs. In particular mixed signal grounding tends to be ah, "Interesting" and often not particularly sane. Some of them are brilliant, but the guy writing them is not always of Jim Williams or Helge Granburgs quality.